# Why won't my output align properly in columns?

Tags: c++

I have no clue why this wont align properly.  I have looked at every other post and topic on aligning basic columns in `cout`, and I have tried them and it just wont do it.

I need 3 columns to look like so:

```
1      0       /sbin/init                                 
949    1       /usr/sbin/sshd -D -d                       
27282  949     sshd: salvucwa [ priv]                   
27323  27282   sshd: salvucwa@pts/31                  
27324  27323   -bash                                  
27425  27324   script                                 
27426  27425   bash -i
```

To do this, I am using this code:

```cpp
void printData(vector<string> tree) {    
    
    for (int i = tree.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        string print = tree.at(i);
        string pid = print.substr(0, print.find(" "));
        print = print.substr(print.find(" "));
        string ppid = print.substr(0, print.find(" "));
        print = print.substr(print.find(" "));
        string cmd = print;
        
        cout << left << setw(5) << pid;
        cout  << ppid;
        cout << setw(50) << cmd << endl;
    }
}
```

The 50 was just a placeholder as I was trying much too large numbers to get it to work, but it hasn't.  It aligns the first and second columns just fine, but it ends up printing like this:

```
1       0   /sbin/init                                 
949     1   /usr/sbin/sshd -D -d                       
27282   949   sshd: salvucwa [ priv]                   
27323   27282   sshd: salvucwa@pts/31                  
27324   27323   -bash                                  
27425   27324   script                                 
27426   27425   bash -i
```

This first 2 columns are aligned perfectly, but the last one always follows the 2nd column and will not change.

Changing the length of the second `setw(5)` in the code block also only increases or decreases the space between the first 2 columns, not the last one.  Also, changing the last `setw()` does not seem to have an affect.

Why is this not aligning properly?  Sorry, as this is probably a dumb question, but every other post on the same topic I have found does not appear to have a fix and only talks about 2 columns (which my first 2 columns are fine).

Comment: Could you try and make a [mre]? It's much easier for us to try out the code that way.

Comment: You don't need to set the width of the `cmd` column.

Comment: This output doesn't look like it's coming from the code you showed. Where are the spaces between the columns coming from?

Comment: The first two calls to `setw` should surely be `7` and `8` respectively.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/Qo6FnH

Comment: use `setw()` to control the total width of the columns you want to print to. Use the specifiers  `std::left` and std::right` and you will se it is easier to control

Comment: @arfneto Isn't that what they're doing?

Comment: No @Barmar . One must include the_ total_ expected width for each and every column and insert `std::left` or `std::right` when needed. When you sum up all `setw()` widths you then get the total of columns in the output. If somebody opens the question I can show you an example.

Comment: I do not think that there are missing debugging details... it would be good to have a piece of code to compile anyway... SO reviewers seems to be a bit pedantic sometimes

Comment: @arfneto Look at my ideone.com code. It works as expected without the total width.

Comment: since `cout` has a ton of overloads we must note that if the first columns come from numbers or from text it makes for a different scenario

Comment: about the "expected" I think we must wait for the author opinion

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code it's impossible to tell precisely what you're doing wrong, but I'm sure that the code you've provided is not the code that you used to print this.

You are most likely using an insufficient column size to print the numeric data.  If your data is 5 characters long, printing as you have:

```
cout << left << setw(5) << "01234";
cout << left << setw(5) << "56789" << endl;
```

will result in something which looks like this:

```
0123456789
```

I would encourage that you use a larger number, such as 10 in your `setw` manipulation.  This will align your data and prevent you from needing to add spaces, so long as it's larger than your largest value.

I wrote a horrifying test to prove this out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    vector<int> numbers = { 1, 0, 949, 1, 27282, 949, 27323, 27282, 27324, 27323, 27425, 27324, 27426, 27525 };

    vector<string> words = 
    {
        "/sbin/init",
        "/usr/sbin/sshd -D -d",
        "sshd: salvucwa [ priv]",
        "-bash",
        "script",
        "bash - i"
    };


    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[0]
            << setw(10) << numbers[1]
            << setw(50)<< words[0] << endl;
    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[2]
            << setw(10) << numbers[3]
            << setw(50)<< words[1] << endl;
    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[4]
            << setw(10) << numbers[5]
            << setw(50)<< words[2] << endl;
    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[6]
            << setw(10) << numbers[7]
            << setw(50)<< words[3] << endl;
    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[8]
            << setw(10) << numbers[9]
            << setw(50)<< words[4] << endl;
    cout << left    << setw(10) << numbers[10]
            << setw(10) << numbers[11]
            << setw(50)<< words[5] << endl;

}
```

This outputs:

```
1         0         /sbin/init                                        
949       1         /usr/sbin/sshd -D -d                              
27282     949       sshd: salvucwa [ priv]                            
27323     27282     -bash                                             
27324     27323     script                                            
27425     27324     bash - i
```

Comment: It was in a loop, and I went ahead and included it.  I tried a single cout statement you provided in your answer at the bottom, and it is still not aligned (like in the first output shown).  The only think that changed from changing the widths from 5 to 10 was the space from the 1st and second column is much larger now, but the issue with that last column is still there.  The input vector has the correct strings and it separates them correctly in the first half of the method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in the posted approach.

- It doesn't take into account the real length of the strings, using `std::setw(5)` and only before `pid`.
- It doesn't consider that the source string may contain more then one space between the fields. For example, `"27324  27323   -bash"` would be parsed as `pid = "27324"`, `ppid = ""`, `cmd = "27323   -bash"`

A lot of copies are also unnecessary performed.

A possible implementation that takes care of the previous points may be the following

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void printData(std::vector<std::string> const& tree)
{    
    auto is_space = [](char ch) -> bool { 
        return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
    };
    
    for (auto row{std::rbegin(tree)}, last_row{std::rend(tree)};
         row != last_row; ++row)
    {
        auto first = std::begin(*row);
        auto last = std::end(*row);
        auto pid_first = std::find_if_not(first, last, is_space);
        auto pid_last = std::find_if(pid_first, last, is_space);
        std::string pid(pid_first, pid_last);  // You may use a std::string_view 

        auto ppid_first = std::find_if_not(pid_last, last, is_space);
        auto ppid_last = std::find_if(ppid_first, last, is_space);
        std::string ppid(ppid_first, ppid_last);

        auto cmd_first = std::find_if_not(ppid_last, last, is_space);
        std::string cmd(cmd_first, last);
        
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(8) << pid
                  << std::setw(8) << ppid
                  << std::setw(50) << cmd << '\n';
    }
}
```